# derive black scholes greeks

Tags: black-scholes-merton

I am reading a paper and get a problem here, the following terms are all from standard BS models.
the paper says using the well known fact
$$Se^{-q(T-t)}N^{'}(d1)=Ke^{-r(T-t)}N^{'}(d2)$$ here the differentiation is respect to $T$.For instance $N^{'}(T^2+1)=2T$

So anyone could give some hints to get this fact?

Comment: I suppose $q$ is a continuous yield dividend and $r$ the risk-free rate. But be careful, $N^\prime$ is most likely not the differential operator here! It is the probability density function of the standard normal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first equality is a bit tedious to derive but straight-forward. As commented by vanguard2k, the notation $N'(x)$ is meant to denote the density function of the standard normal distribution:
$$ N'(x) = n(x) := \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} $$.
Simply insert the $d_{i}$ terms,
$$ d_1 = \frac{\log\left(\frac{S}{K}\right) + (r-q+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)(T-t)}{\sigma\sqrt{T-t}} $$
$$ d_2 = \frac{\log\left(\frac{S}{K}\right) + (r-q-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)(T-t)}{\sigma\sqrt{T-t}} $$
and rearrange.

The second equality cannot be, in general, correct. Simply write out the lhs to see that. Or note that the maximum of the standard normal pdf is slighlty less than 0.4. So for T>0.2, the equality is incorrect.

Comment: Thx. Totally agreed about N'(x)